# Установил Litebox на сайт, перестал работать hide...

Tags: javascript

На сайте, для реализации спойлера стоит такая штучка:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$(".more").hide();   
    $(".podr").click(function(){
     $(this).next(".more").slideToggle(300)
      return false;
    }); 
});
```

Захотелось установить красивую галерею. Выбрал `Litebox`. Если на одной и той же странице подключены и файлы галереи и скрипт, приведенный выше, то скрипт не прячет элементы. Hide не срабатывает. Ну и `slideToggl`e тоже.

Если не подключать litebox все работает нормально. Что можно сделать, чтобы одновременно и то и другое работало корректно?

Comment: $(this).next(".more").slideToggle(300) return false; // точно не надо ; перед return?

Comment: Не знаю). Но работает, если не подключать галерею)

Comment: точка с запятой ничего н изменила

Comment: как же мне надоели вопросы такого рода...<br>
Открываем любой браузерный отладчик(хромовский, firebug, абсолютно неважно), находм ошибку, устраняем и радуемся жизни...<br>Если же не получится устранить то тогда уже пишите что именно у вас не получается и тогда уже будем разбиратся...<br>
<small><i>Ато вы сейчас как мне раньше на ремонт компы приносили...Я спрашиваю че с ним, а мне говорят поламался, сделаете?:)</i></small>

Comment: ну, может кто сталкивался...
P.S. Rf же мне надоели такие всезнайки...
Которые знают и умеют все, но, увы, не делятся ничем полезным...

Comment: я вообще с javascript не очень знаком) могу только чуть переделать готовое. 
А те люди, которые долго с ним работают, имеют опыт вполне могут знать в чем затык.

Comment: они просто забыли, что не так давно, им самим так же отвечали на их вопросы

Comment: Таких вопросов я не задавал никогда... Типа не работает - гребитесь...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@oleg_ismaylov](/users/2122/oleg_ismaylov), попробуй в html-странице (или шаблоне) загрузить Litebox раньше или наоборот, позже загрузки спойлера.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, если спойлер поставить раньше, все ок. 
Но интересно было бы узнать причину...
Видимо в litebox'e переопределяется функция hide?

Comment: Да ... конфликт